# Query for searching the name alphabetically

Tags: sql

I have used the `LIKE` condition, but it required me to enter the full name into the database to find the name.

```java
if (searchby.equals("Name"))
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        System.out.println("\n Driver loaded");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:wanisamajDB");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Name FROM FAMILYcensus WHERE Name LIKE '"+ tfsearch.getText()+"'");
        //  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Name FROM FAMILYcensus WHERE Name LIKE );
        System.out.println("Hi");

        rs.next();
        String names = rs.getString("NAME");
        System.out.println("NAME: " + names );

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "RECORD FOUND");

        tasearch.setText(names);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION " + e);
    }
```

Comment: What about using the `%` operator like this: `SELECT Name FROM FAMILYcensus WHERE Name LIKE '%"+ tfsearch.getText()+"%'"`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM FAMILYcensus WHERE Name LIKE '%"+ tfsearch.getText()+"%'ORDER BY Name ASC"` `tfsearch` here is a `JTextField`?

Comment: if i understand the question, you want the names in a vertical list with carriage returns, not on the same line. The issue is this line:  sb.append(name + " ");  instead of " ", you should use   System.getProperty("line.separator")

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't really understand your question clearly, but from what I understand, I'll post something that may help in solving your problem.

Put your search string inside % as EmCo commented `"'%"+ tfsearch.getText()+"%'"`

The % before and after the search string has different uses when you omit either one of this. See *[String Comparison Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)* on how to use it.

Now your another problem will be:

You want the name in alphabetical order. For this you need to include `ORDER BY`. Then your query string will be.

```
"SELECT 
        Name 
   FROM FAMILYcensus 
  WHERE Name LIKE '%" + tfsearch.getText() +"%' 
  ORDER BY Name ASC"
```

Your search may result in more than one. Using just `rs.next();` and `String names = rs.getString("NAME");` will get only the first records I guess.

You can try this code:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
while(rs.next){
    names.add(rs.getString('Name'));
}
```

The code I've provided is not tested. Though it will be like that or similar. Have a try if you still have a problem with your current code.

Comment: soory sir now with ur help i am getting the result alphabeticaly but it only showing only singal name in textarea i want all the name starting with that alphabet in textbox from my DB

Comment: What do you mean single name? is it single result? If yes, the did you use the while loop in my post. If no that may be the answer you need. Also you need to loop the results in your textarea. Please provide the code when you display it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the result set:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    String name = rs.getString("Name");
    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
}
```

It looks like you had it and commented it out? If you want to store it in a list you had it right. If you want to put all of the results into a `String` for that `tasearch.setText()` you could:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (rs.next()) {
    String name = rs.getString("Name");
    sb.append(name + " ");
}
String names = sb.toString().trim();
tasearch.setText(names);
```

Answer (score 0):

WhiteFang34 also said you need to iterate. But also you need to change to WHERE clause:

```
"SELECT * FROM FAMILYcensus WHERE Name > '"+ tfsearch.getText()+"' ORDER BY Name ASC LIMIT "+MAXRESULTS;
```

Note that limiting the number of results is a good idea here.

Comment: *"Note that limiting the number of results is a good idea here."* - you are making assumptions about the requirements that may be unwarranted.  Maybe a better idea would be to display the results a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

and

```
sb.append(name + " ");
```

do

```
List names = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and

```
names.add(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (rs.next()) {
String name = rs.getString("Name");
sb.append(name + " ");
}
```

Use this:

```
List<String> lstNames = new ArrayList<String>();
while (rs.next()) {
   lstNames.add(rs.getString("Name"));
}
```