# Problem with alphabetic sorting

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [i want to search the name alphabetically required query for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521433/i-want-to-search-the-name-alphabetically-required-query-for-that)

I am searching the person name by alphabet and I am getting the name alphabetically as well but only first occurence of that alphabet. I want whole list of name starting from that alphabet. What am I doing wrong?

```
if (searchby.equals("Name"))
//if(cbsearch.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Name"))
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        System.out.println("\n Driver loaded");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:wanisamajDB");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

        // ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Name FROM FAMILYcensus WHERE Name LIKE '"+ tfsearch.getText()+"'");
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM FAMILYcensus WHERE Name LIKE '%"+ tfsearch.getText()+"%'ORDER BY Name ASC");
        System.out.println("Hi");

        // List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        // while(rs.next()) {
        //     boolean add1 = names.add(rs.getString("Name"));
        // }

        rs.next();
        String names = rs.getString("Name");
        System.out.println("Name: " + names );

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "RECORD FOUND");

        // tasearch.setText(add1);
        tasearch.setText(names);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION " + e);
    }
}
```